# Jenkins call script after build success

Tags: docker, jenkins, odoo, cicd

I want to Jenkins call a shell script from another docker container.

I don't know Jenkins can do this, and what is the best way to make it.

[image]

In one machine, I have this containers:

| Service | IP (Docker network) | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **ERP system** | 172.74.42.2 | **Odoo 14** ERP system what work with many plugin. If a plugin got new functions or fixes some bugs, need to restart the system after the **pull**, then **update** the plugin. (I write a shell script what run in ssh after push commits. |
| **Jenkins** | 172.74.42.3 | In here I want to call the shell script after the build is success |

The Jenkins is work. So the connect between the github and jenkins is good.

I try to write shell commands in **Jenkins** file. But I think this is a dumb way...

Comment: A more typical Docker-based flow would do the "pull changes" step in Jenkins, the "update modules" step in a Dockerfile, and then would have Jenkins build a new image and launch a new container in place of the "restart" step.  Is this workflow an option for you?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a git question.

Comment: @DavidMaze I didn't think of that. Not bad option is this. Thanks!